# Handling ' and " on an Insert query

Tags: sqlite

Based on a Textbox object, I am using an INSERT query to add the text into a record to a SQLite table:

```
INSERT INTO tblActivity ([Activity_Category], 
[Activity_Category_Sub], 
[Activity_Start], 
[Activity_End], 
[Activity_Duration]) 
Values ('" + clVariables.strActivityCurrent + "', '" 
+ clVariables.strActivitySubCurrent + "', '" 
+ clVariables.datActivityStart.ToString() + "', '" 
+ clVariables.datActivityEnd.ToString() + "', " 
+ clVariables.dblActivityDuration + ")"
```

It is possible that `clVariables.strActivitySubCurrent` could contain either " or ', and I wanted to know the correct way to be able to add these characters to the field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use a prepared statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblActivity (
    "Activity_Category", 
    "Activity_Category_Sub", 
    "Activity_Start", 
    "Activity_End", 
    "Activity_Duration") 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

You then bind the values to the parameters in the prepared statement (the `?`, so we're using positional parameters here) when you execute it, and you don't have to work out how to quote the strings. Even better, the DB engine doesn't have to recompile the statement for each row you execute.

The only time this is awkward is if you are using the SQLite shell, which doesn't support parameters (there's not really a true host language to do the binding in) but you can do bulk import there in other ways (and you can get away without them for *ad hoc* querying work). But I'm guessing that you're hosting in another language, probably C#, in which case you've got no excuse for doing it wrong. It doesn't take more work to code, but it does take *different* work.

(Now, if you were taking table or column names from the user that would be different, as they can't be parameterized. It would also be a little bit horrifying.)